# Smooth Animations with ActionEvents in Java

Tags: java, animation, timer

I am attempting to learn more about Java GUI programming, specifically animations for games. I am referencing a program found on http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c6/s4.html called "SubKiller.java". The source is as followed:

```
import java.awt.*;        
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 * This panel implements a simple arcade game in which the user tries to blow
 * up a "submarine" (a black oval) by dropping "depth charges" (a red disk) from 
 * a "boat" (a blue roundrect).  The user moves the boat with the left- and 
 * right-arrow keys and drops the depth charge with the down-arrow key.
 * The sub moves left and right erratically along the bottom of the panel.
 * This class contains a main() routine to allow it to be run as a program.
 */
public class SubKiller extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Sub Killer Game");
        SubKiller content = new SubKiller();
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setSize(600, 480);
        window.setLocation(100,100);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        window.setResizable(false);  // User can't change the window's size.
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private Timer timer;        // Timer that drives the animation.

    private int width, height;  // The size of the panel -- the values are set
                                //    the first time the paintComponent() method
                                //    is called.  This class is not designed to
                                //    handle changes in size; once the width and
                                //    height have been set, they are not changed.
                                //    Note that width and height cannot be set
                                //    in the constructor because the width and
                                //    height of the panel have not been set at
                                //    the time that the constructor is called.

    private Boat boat;          // The boat, bomb, and sub objects are defined
    private Bomb bomb;          //    by nested classes Boat, Bomb, and Submarine,
    private Submarine sub;      //    which are defined later in this class.
                                //    Note that the objects are created in the
                                //    paintComponent() method, after the width
                                //    and height of the panel are known.


    /**
     * The constructor sets the background color of the panel, creates the
     * timer, and adds a KeyListener, FocusListener, and MouseListener to the
     * panel.  These listeners, as well as the ActionListener for the timer
     * are defined by anonymous inner classes.  The timer will run only
     * when the panel has the input focus.
     */
    public SubKiller() {

        setBackground( new Color(0,200,0) ); 

        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
                // Defines the action taken each time the timer fires.
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (boat != null) {
                    boat.updateForNewFrame();
                    bomb.updateForNewFrame();
                    sub.updateForNewFrame();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer( 30, action );  // Fires every 30 milliseconds.

        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
                // The mouse listener simply requests focus when the user
                // clicks the panel.
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                requestFocus();
            }
        } );

        addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {
                // The focus listener starts the timer when the panel gains
                // the input focus and stops the timer when the panel loses
                // the focus.  It also calls repaint() when these events occur.
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
                timer.start();
                repaint();
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
                timer.stop();
                repaint();
            }
        } );

        addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {
                // The key listener responds to keyPressed events on the panel. Only
                // the left-, right-, and down-arrow keys have any effect.  The left- and
                // right-arrow keys move the boat while down-arrow releases the bomb.
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                int code = evt.getKeyCode();  // Which key was pressed?
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                        // Move the boat left.  (If this moves the boat out of the frame, its
                        // position will be adjusted in the boat.updateForNewFrame() method.)
                    boat.centerX -= 15;
                }
                else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {  
                        // Move the boat right.  (If this moves boat out of the frame, its
                        // position will be adjusted in the boat.updateForNewFrame() method.)
                    boat.centerX += 15;
                }
                else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                        // Start the bomb falling, if it is not already falling.
                    if ( bomb.isFalling == false )
                        bomb.isFalling = true;
                }
            }
        } );

    } // end constructor


    /**
     * The paintComponent() method draws the current state of the game.  It
     * draws a gray or cyan border around the panel to indicate whether or not
     * the panel has the input focus.  It draws the boat, sub, and bomb by
     * calling their respective draw() methods.
     */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);  // Fill panel with background color, green.

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        if (boat == null) {
                // The first time that paintComponent is called, it assigns
                // values to the instance variables.
            width = getWidth();
            height = getHeight();
            boat = new Boat();
            sub = new Submarine();
            bomb = new Bomb();
        }

        if (hasFocus())
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("CLICK TO ACTIVATE", 20, 30);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        g.drawRect(0,0,width-1,height-1);  // Draw a 3-pixel border.
        g.drawRect(1,1,width-3,height-3);
        g.drawRect(2,2,width-5,height-5);

        boat.draw(g);
        sub.draw(g);
        bomb.draw(g);

    } // end paintComponent()


    /**
     * This nested class defines the boat.  Note that its constructor cannot
     * be called until the width of the panel is known!
     */
    private class Boat {
        int centerX, centerY;  // Current position of the center of the boat.
        Boat() { // Constructor centers the boat horizontally, 80 pixels from top.
            centerX = width/2;
            centerY = 80;
        }
        void updateForNewFrame() { // Makes sure boat has not moved off screen.
            if (centerX < 0)
                centerX = 0;
            else if (centerX > width)
                centerX = width;
        }
        void draw(Graphics g) {  // Draws the boat at its current location.
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRoundRect(centerX - 40, centerY - 20, 80, 40, 20, 20);
        }
    } // end nested class Boat


    /**
     * This nested class defines the bomb. 
     */
    private class Bomb {
        int centerX, centerY; // Current position of the center of the bomb.
        boolean isFalling;    // If true, the bomb is falling; if false, it
                             // is attached to the boat.
        Bomb() { // Constructor creates a bomb that is initially attached to boat.
            isFalling = false;
        }
        void updateForNewFrame() {  // If bomb is falling, take appropriate action.
            if (isFalling) {
                if (centerY > height) {
                        // Bomb has missed the submarine.  It is returned to its
                        // initial state, with isFalling equal to false.
                    isFalling = false;
                }
                else if (Math.abs(centerX - sub.centerX) <= 36 &&
                        Math.abs(centerY - sub.centerY) <= 21) {
                        // Bomb has hit the submarine.  The submarine
                        // enters the "isExploding" state.
                    sub.isExploding = true;
                    sub.explosionFrameNumber = 1;
                    isFalling = false;  // Bomb reappears on the boat.
                }
                else {
                        // If the bomb has not fallen off the panel or hit the
                        // sub, then it is moved down 10 pixels.
                    centerY += 10;
                }
            }
        }
        void draw(Graphics g) { // Draw the bomb.
            if ( ! isFalling ) {  // If not falling, set centerX and centerY
                                  // to show the bomb on the bottom of the boat.
                centerX = boat.centerX;
                centerY = boat.centerY + 23;
            }
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(centerX - 8, centerY - 8, 16, 16);
        }
    } // end nested class Bomb


    /**
     * This nested class defines the sub.  Note that its constructor cannot
     * be called until the width of the panel is known!
     */
    private class Submarine {
        int centerX, centerY; // Current position of the center of the sub.
        boolean isMovingLeft; // Tells whether the sub is moving left or right
        boolean isExploding;  // Set to true when the sub is hit by the bomb.
        int explosionFrameNumber;  // If the sub is exploding, this is the number
                                   //   of frames since the explosion started.
        Submarine() {  // Create the sub at a random location 40 pixels from bottom.
            centerX = (int)(width*Math.random());
            centerY = height - 40;
            isExploding = false;
            isMovingLeft = (Math.random() < 0.5);
        }
        void updateForNewFrame() { // Move sub or increase explosionFrameNumber.
            if (isExploding) {
                    // If the sub is exploding, add 1 to explosionFrameNumber.
                    // When the number reaches 15, the explosion ends and the
                    // sub reappears in a random position.
                explosionFrameNumber++;
                if (explosionFrameNumber == 15) { 
                    centerX = (int)(width*Math.random());
                    centerY = height - 40;
                    isExploding = false;
                    isMovingLeft = (Math.random() < 0.5);
                }
            }
            else { // Move the sub.
                if (Math.random() < 0.04) {  
                        // In one frame out of every 25, on average, the sub
                        // reverses its direction of motion.
                    isMovingLeft = ! isMovingLeft; 
                }
                if (isMovingLeft) { 
                        // Move the sub 5 pixels to the left.  If it moves off
                        // the left edge of the panel, move it back to the left
                        // edge and start it moving to the right.
                    centerX -= 5;  
                    if (centerX <= 0) {  
                        centerX = 0; 
                        isMovingLeft = false; 
                    }
                }
                else {
                        // Move the sub 5 pixels to the right.  If it moves off
                        // the right edge of the panel, move it back to the right
                        // edge and start it moving to the left.
                    centerX += 5;         
                    if (centerX > width) {  
                        centerX = width;   
                        isMovingLeft = true; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        void draw(Graphics g) {  // Draw sub and, if it is exploding, the explosion.
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(centerX - 30, centerY - 15, 60, 30);
            if (isExploding) {
                    // Draw an "explosion" that grows in size as the number of
                    // frames since the start of the explosion increases.
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillOval(centerX - 4*explosionFrameNumber,
                        centerY - 2*explosionFrameNumber,
                        8*explosionFrameNumber,
                        4*explosionFrameNumber);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillOval(centerX - 2*explosionFrameNumber,
                        centerY - explosionFrameNumber/2,
                        4*explosionFrameNumber,
                        explosionFrameNumber);
            }
        }
    } // end nested class Submarine    


} // end class SubKiller
```

Looking through the source code, I can't find out why the boat the user controls doesn't move smoothly like the submarine. I see they both operate under the same timer... I'm assuming this is because the program is looking for an action event each time iteration or something? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Animation is the illusion of change over time, in this case, the change is sudden and immediate in a large single step of 15 pixels, but the sub is allowed to (constantly) move about a 5 pixel step (it never stops), making the animation "look" more smooth.  One method might be to reduce the step of the "boat", but introduce a "target" point which the boat will need several frame cycles in order to reach.  You could then look at easements to make the animation look more natural

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend using a dedicate animation library, as it's just simpler to manage, but you can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335787/how-can-i-implement-easing-functions-with-a-thread/28338188#28338188) for a discussion on how one might be implemented.  I'd also HIGHLY recommend you do a LOT of reading on animation theory in general (not just related to computer games or algorithms)

Comment: You could also apply a movement delta, which is increased the longer the user holds a key down, this would make the boat appear to speed up and down.  This would also mean, if the user changed directions, it would take time for that change to occur, as it would need to first overcome the opposite movement delta...

Comment: I understand how animation works fairly well, and I'm not looking to add any kind of easing on the ship's movement for just that reason. (slow to move opposite directions once it has a velocity in another direction)