# Any java formula/class to make smooth position change? [JAVA]

Tags: java, animation

I need to make an animation to change object position with the acceleration to the center and slowing to the end.

I have 2 values: `CurrentPos` and `PosWhereNeed`.

I have some formula: `CurrentPos + (PosWhereNeed - CurrentPos) / Modifer` (`Modifer` controls the speed).

But this formula has a sharp beginning without acceleration, only slowing on the end.

And it has some drops on the end (not slow changing position).

Comment: Google *sigmoid function*.

Comment: So you want [easement control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335787/how-can-i-implement-easing-functions-with-a-thread/28338188#28338188)

Answer (score 0):

If what you have already works, then calculate what it would be to get to the halfway point, and copy and reverse it to get to the rest of the way there.

Alternatively, pick any point along the way instead of halfway (like a quarter way) and use that for the transition, and have a constant speed between those two points.